# How to assign values from a file to variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a text file and I wish to make code that puts the numbers into an array.

The program is required to read the data for each member from the text file. The program then uses this data to find then display the biggest value. The names of every member who has a value more than 70% of the largest is to be written on an empty text file so that the file can be printed out later.

```
Nikolai,Bryant,145.6
Susan,Brown,34.2
Teressa,Jones,398.5
Martin,Daly,256.9
Ross,Durrant,409.0
Greg,Watson,99.2
Wendy,Russell,87.4
Pamela,Adkins,73.6
Ian,Hunter,385.7
James,Kerr,505.2
Lesley,Wallace,68.4
Kim,Pettigrew,256.4
Steven,Johnstone,23.4
Ali,Hussain,12.1
Hasan,Abbas,302.0
Jacek,Nowak,199.9
Mirka,Kowalski,176.8
Rudo,Hyper,120.2
Tisa,Sullivan,484.2
Albert,Nvodo,385.8
```

So far all I have is this:

```vb
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "H:\S5\Computing\Programming\members.txt"
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I recommend that you look into the `TextFieldParser` class. You can parse the file, read the numbers, add them to a collection and then, if required, convert that to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `Imports System.IO` at the top of you code file. This has a `File` class which contains the `.ReadAllLines` method. This method will return an array of all the lines in the text file.

'String.Split' will return an array of of the fields in the line which were delimited (separated) by a comma. The small c after "," tells the compiler that this is `Char` which what the `.Split` method expects.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "H:\S5\Computing\Programming\members.txt"        
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
    'Declare an array to hold your numbers VB arrays are declared arr(UBound)
    'UBound is upper bound referring to highest index
    'The highest index would be 1 less the lenght because indexes start at 0
    Dim numbers(lines.Length - 1) As Single
    Dim index As Integer 'Will be the index for the numbers array
    'From the lines array we can loop through each line
    For Each s As String In lines
        Dim fields = s.Split(","c)
        'Your fields array will have 3 elements, a first name at position (index) 0, last name at 1 and number at 2
        'You only want the number - but it is not a number yet, it is still a string
        'So we do a CSng to change it to a Single
        numbers(index) = CSng(fields(2))
        index += 1 'shortcut way to write index = index + 1
    Next
    For Each n As Single In numbers
        Debug.Print(n.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

The .TexFieldParser suggested by @jmcilhinney in comments has some extra features which would come in handy but this should get you started.

Comment: parts of the code is coming up as an error.

`Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)`

`file` is not declared

Comment: Did you import Systems.IO? See the first sentence in my answer.